# VB6: Global Variable that it's value can be changed by different events

Tags: variables, listbox, vb6, global-variables

I wanted to create a shopping cart form in visual basic 6.0 and I created this form using listBox and other buttons to add or remove tools. The tools list is found in another separate form. The add and remove functions are working as intended but my main problem is that when the shopping cart form is closed and then reopened, the information isn't retained and rolls back to its empty state.

What could I possibly use or do, I am new to using visual basic 6.0 and doesn't know any of its basic syntax, I am only a little knowledgeable with python or c++.

I have tried using variables using dim temp as string and then using if statements during form_load of the shopping cart form that checks if the temp variable is not equal to "" which means is that it has something in it and then add it to the listbox of the shopping cart form.

I have checked that the if statement is working and the one that is not working is the variable itself, so I researched about it and figured that I needed the variable to be a global variable that is why instead of dim temp as string, I did public temp as string and yet it still doesn't store the text value of the listbox of the tool list form.

I also considered using an array of string but it turns out you cannot use a public dynamic array in VB6

What wanted to happen is that i'll have a temporary storing mechanism that will store all the added tools to the cart and when the shopping cart form is closed and reopened, a simple if statement in form_load or lostfocus or any event that could be used, will return the stored information.

Comment: Add a Module (Project > Add Module) and declare your global variables Public in that. See https://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/lesson2.1.html.

Comment: By "shopping cart form is closed and reopened" do you mean you application is restarted? Global variables will not survive app restart so you'll need real persistence here. You can safely skip global variables approach if you are going to write the data to files/database.

Comment: _"you cannot use a public dynamic array in VB6"_   Uh, what? Sure you can. Perhaps you could explain that a bit, or ask a new question if you're having issues with arrays.